# What's the PHP equivalent of Python's locals()?

Tags: php, python, scope

I know [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) in PHP is a rough equivalent of Python's [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals), but is there an equivalent of [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals)?

My Python:

```
>>> g = 'global'
>>> def test():
...     l = 'local'
...     print repr(globals());
...     print repr(locals());
... 
>>> 
>>> test()
{'g': 'global', [...other stuff in the global scope...]}
{'l': 'local'}
```

My PHP port:

```
<?php
$g = 'global';
function test(){ 
    $l = 'local';
    print_r($GLOBALS);
    //...please fill in the dots...:-)
}
test();
?>
Array
(
    [g] => global
    [...other stuff in the global scope...]
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`get_defined_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) is what you're looking for.

```
function test(){
    $a = 'local';
    $b = 'another';
    print_r(get_defined_vars());
}

test();

#Array
#(
#    [a] => local
#    [b] => another
#)
```

Comment: Nice.. They should make this a suggestion in the manual search. I only got stuff that starts with var.